# Convert the function PERCENTILE_CONT for SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query which I created on my test server having SQL 2014. I am now to deploy it to another server unfortunately the other instance is on SQL Server 2008 R2. Can you help me convert the `PERCENTILE_CONT` function to be compatible on SQL Server 2008 R2?

Basically I have a database of servers with there corresponding MBperSec. I want to get the upper and lower limit across all the servers. Percentile25 is the upper limit and Percentile75.

```
Percentile25 = (PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY x.MBperSec) OVER (PARTITION BY x.block, x.operation)),
Percentile75 = (PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY x.MBperSec) OVER (PARTITION BY x.block, x.operation)),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a reasonable approximation -- really more `percentile_disc()` than `percentile_cont()`, but I don't know if that makes a difference:

```
select . . .,
       max(case when seqnum <= cnt * 0.25 then x.MBperSec end) over (partition by x.block, x.operation) as percentile_25,
       max(case when seqnum <= cnt * 0.75 then x.MBperSec end) over (partition by x.block, x.operation) as percentile_75
from (select x.*,
             row_number() over (partition x.block, x.operation
                                order by x.MBperSec
                               ) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition x.block, x.operation) as cnt
      from Table_CPU x
      where x.Operation = 'reading' and
            replace(x.block, 'KB', '') in ('64')
     ) x
```

Comment: As per research PERCENTILE_DISC returns a value in your set/window, whereas PERCENTILE_CONT will interpolate. I think PERCENTILE_CONT would give me a more precise output still but thanks @Gordon Linoff